# Google Script - get data from Gmail into Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, google-apps

I have been looking around here on SO and on Google, but I cannot find anything that is working.

So when I am running my code below, I am getting the result on the image.

I want to extract data from the *newest/most recent* `thread` in mails that have a specific label.

However, in my `Gmail`, I only have the 3 mails under `"Action"-label` that I have highlighted in bold.
The other mails have been deleted, hence, they are in trash, but do still have the "Action" label.

I want to only show the mails that I have `"Action"-label` on - meaning that I only want the newest `thread` time/date, subject line as well as the ID, so I can create a link to that mail.

[image: Google Sheet data example]

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var query = "label:action -label:trash -label:action-done -from:me";

  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
      var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

      for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++)
      {
        var mId = messages[j].getId()
        var from = messages[j].getFrom();
        var cc = messages[j].getCc();
        var time = messages[j].getDate()
        var sub = messages[j].getSubject();

        ss.appendRow([from, cc, time, sub, 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have repeated `for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {  var messages = threads[i].getMessages();` twice, which certainly doesn't help to get the correct output. For what it's worth, I don't get deleted emails when running your script.

Comment: @6'whitemale yeah that was just a "typo", but I get the same result. Have you tried keeping a mail that was a reply to another one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I managed to solve it, by finding the max index in the array.
I have commented the code, so it can help others. Thanks, all.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Use sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Gmail query
  var query = "label:support -label:trash -label:support-done -from:me";
  // Search in Gmail, bind to array
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  // Loop through query results
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
    // Get messages in thread, add to array
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    // Used to find max index in array
    var max = messages[0];
    var maxIndex = 0;

    // Loop through array to find maxIndexD = most recent mail
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      if (messages[j] > max) {
        maxIndex = j;
        max = messages[j];
      }
    } 
    // Find data
    var mId = messages[maxIndex].getId() // ID used to create mail link
    var from = messages[maxIndex].getFrom();
    var cc = messages[maxIndex].getCc();
    var time = threads[i].getLastMessageDate()
    var sub = messages[maxIndex].getSubject();
    // Write data to sheet
    ss.appendRow([from, cc, time, sub, 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## What do you mean by recent?

How about adding **newer_than:3d** to the search?
You can test the search in your own Gmail account and when it's doing what you want then just paste it into the query.

Comment: I get trash mails when I use newer_than in Gmail, however, if I use my query `label:action -label:trash -label:action-done -from:me` in Gmail, then I get the right result. The script is still showing the wrong result.

Comment: How about **label:action newer_than:3d -in:trash**.  Actually, I don't have to say not in trash in my account.  I actually have to use **in:trash** if I want to get it out of trash.