# Google script that already fetches email infos but needs attachment name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

CONTEXT

- I'm using a script to fetch emails that I found here (from  [Niclas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042624/niclas), I think): [fetching emails script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417288/google-script-get-data-from-gmail-into-sheet)
- I've adapted it to my needs and it works very well!

WHAT I'VE TESTED

- I saw [getDescription()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/attachment#getdescription) from the Google script Class Attachment but couldn't get it to work and I'm not even sure if that's the way to go

WHAT I WOULD WANT

- In addition, I would like to fetch the attachments filenames since It's a distinctive mark on each email
- Any help would me very appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Modifications:

Do the following modifications to the answer of the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417288/google-script-get-data-from-gmail-into-sheet) you mentioned in your question:

- Add these lines:

  ```
  var attachments = messages[maxIndex].getAttachments();
  var attNames = attachments.map(att=>att.getName());
  ```
- and modify this one:

  ```
  ss.appendRow([from, cc, time, sub,...attNames ,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
  ```

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Use sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Gmail query
  var query = "label:support -label:trash -label:support-done -from:me";
  // Search in Gmail, bind to array
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  // Loop through query results
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
    // Get messages in thread, add to array
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    // Used to find max index in array
    var max = messages[0];
    var maxIndex = 0;

    // Loop through array to find maxIndexD = most recent mail
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
      if (messages[j] > max) {
        maxIndex = j;
        max = messages[j];
      }
    } 
    // Find data
    var mId = messages[maxIndex].getId() // ID used to create mail link
    var from = messages[maxIndex].getFrom();
    var cc = messages[maxIndex].getCc();
    var time = threads[i].getLastMessageDate()
    var sub = messages[maxIndex].getSubject();
    var attachments = messages[maxIndex].getAttachments();
    var attNames = attachments.map(att=>att.getName());

    // Write data to sheet
ss.appendRow([from, cc, time, sub,...attNames ,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
  }
}
```

Don't forget to change the value of `query` to your needs.

### References:

- [Class GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

You have to [enable V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#incompatibilities) runtime to be able to use the snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've tested it and it returns for the attachament names things like: "[Ljava.lang.Object;@9d63714". That is not quite what I'm looking for... I'm trying to get things like: "Payment proof Ref. 3498.pdf"